# Unable to change IPv4 properties for a VirtualBox Host-Only Adapter

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox, vagrant

Keeps coming up with:

> In order to configure TCP/IP, you must install and enable a network adapter card.

Using Vagrant and ScotchBox if that helps but also tried with a basic Vagrant box and same issue. Also cannot ping the IP of the VirtualBox machine.

Here is my ipconfig screen:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f85d:6965:31bf:7541%25
    Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.117.65
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

The VirtualBox adapter has a 169 address, probably why I can't ping it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can configure the host-only network adapter setting from within VirtualBox.  File->Preference then use the network tab.

Comment: Ah ok, got another weird issue now, when vagrant creates the Host Only adapter, the ip is now stuck on 192.168.69.2, no matter what the vagrant file says.